# Does separating classes in different modules have performance consequences?

Tags: python, performance, class, optimization, module

Is it better to have all your classes in one module (assuming they are related somehow)
in terms of performance?
Because Python needs to search the module and maybe importing packages to every module takes time?

i.e:

```
├──animals
   └── animals.py
```

animals.py:

```
import stuff

class dog: ...

class cat: ...

class fish: ...
```

or

```
src
├── animals
│   ├── __init__.py       
│   ├── dog.py
|   |── cat.py
|   |── fish.py
└── do_stuff_with_animals.py
```

do_stuff_with_animals.py:

```
from src.animals import dog ,cat ,fish
```

Comment: IIRC there is some caching going on, so you do not need to worry much about such stuff. Your priority should be first to write clean code. Afterwards, if needed, to fix performance bottlenecks (which for sure will not be such as the problem stated here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of where your modules are defined, once you did the import, the "module object" with all the definitions inside it is cached under `sys.modules` (from the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules))

You will "pay" some cost for each import (finding the file, parsing the file and compiling the python code, loading the code into memory, and running it for to evaluate), but in a long running program this shouldn't be an issue - once the modules are loaded, this is cached and module import times are typically negligible (assuming the modules only define classes and don't anything sophisticated).

Comment: what do you mean by "sophisticated"?

Comment: When a module is imported, any python code directly at the root of the module will be executed. So for example, if a module has code at its root (i.e. not inside of any class/function) that tries to mine bitcoin, loading the module will take a while :) If the module only defines classes/functions, or runs other trivial code (such as checking for file existence, etc.), it should load quickly.